# How do I enforce App Check in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I have set up App Check in my Firebase Project, for both my mobile app and my web app.

Once I was done with that, I have enabled App Check in various Firebase products such as Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage, following the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider#enable-enforcement).

However those instructions don't mention Cloud Firestore. How do I enable App Check in Cloud Firestore? The link above doesn't provide any info and I could not find anything in the Cloud Firestore documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*firebaser here*

**Update** (November 10, 2021): Firebase just added support for App Check to Firestore. For this and all the latest releases, check: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/11/whats-new-at-Firebase-Summit-2021.html#Strengthening

---

Old answer , you really should check the update ...

According to the documentation on [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check):

> App Check currently works with the following Firebase products:
>
> - Realtime Database
> - Cloud Storage
> - Cloud Functions (callable functions)

So Cloud Firestore does not yet support App Check. While we're definitely interested adding support for App Check to Firestore in the future, there is no timeline for when this will be available.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's a +1 from me, in favour of adding App Check support to Firestore! :-)

Comment: Today Firebase released AppCheck for Firestore. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/11/whats-new-at-Firebase-Summit-2021.html#Strengthening